# React Router: Get location in container component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to access the active path in the parent component, so that I can vary some CSS depending on the location. Here is `App` - the parent:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="wrapper" >
        <div className="content">
          <Router>
          <div className="container_b">
            <Menu />
            <div>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
              <Route path="/confidence" component={ConfidenceInterval}/>
              <Route path="/proind" component={ProportionTestInd}/>
              <Route path="/prodep" component={ProportionTestDep}/>
            </div>
          </div>
          </Router>
          <div className="push"></div>
        </div>
        <footer className="footer"><Footer /></footer>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think for the App component, you have two options. First one is wrapping App with withRouter higher order component.
React-router provides a higher order component called withRouter, which passes match, history and location props to the component wrapped by it.
(for details please check [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter))

In that case you can to the following

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render(){
    const {location: {pathname}} = this.props // pathname gives you the current path
    return (
      <div className="wrapper" >
        <div className="content">
          <Router>
          <div className="container_b">
            <Menu />
            <div>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
              <Route path="/confidence" component={ConfidenceInterval}/>
              <Route path="/proind" component={ProportionTestInd}/>
              <Route path="/prodep" component={ProportionTestDep}/>
            </div>
          </div>
          </Router>
          <div className="push"></div>
        </div>
        <footer className="footer"><Footer /></footer>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export const WrappedApp = withRouter(App)
```

Second option is, (again for App component) you can use window.location (please check [window.location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)). location.pathname should also give you the current path in that case.

For other components, like Home,ConfidenceInterval etc, Route passes match, history and location props by default so you can make use of them.

Comment: window.location does work but the problem is render() is only called once, not every time the page is changed, so I can't use it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
   const location = useLocation();
   console.log(location.pathname);
   enter code herereturn <span>Path : {location.pathname}</span>
}
```